# Integrating an Apache spark cluster with multiple databases

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, cassandra

My team uses different databases, say mongodb and cassandra.
I need to know if it is possible to integrate a single spark cluster with both mongodb and cassandra clusters.
Or, in other words, is it possible to create dataframes from mongodb and cassandra in the same spark application?

Answer (score 2):

Spark only sees DataFrames and RDDs. It doesn't really matter which database you're using, as long as a connector exists. You can make as many external connections as needed within a single Spark Context

Any data source that's read into those formats can be combined